# Python interpolation sin function using nearest method

Tags: python

I write simple code using interpolation of sin function, nearest method. My question is it's that code it's correct? It seems to me that the function should consist of straight lines. Curved lines appear on the generated graph.

[image]

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d
import math

# Original "data set" --- 21 random numbers between 0 and 1.
x0 = np.arange(9)
y0 = [math.sin(i) for i in x0]

plt.plot(x0, y0, 'o', label='Data')
plt.grid(linestyle="-", color=(0.7, 0.8, 1.0))

x = np.linspace(0, 8, len(x0)*2)

# Available options for interp1d
options = ('linear', 'nearest')

f = interp1d(x0, y0, kind='nearest')    # interpolation function
plt.plot(x, f(x), label='nearest')      # plot of interpolated data

plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

EDIT:

I woudl like to impelment own interpolation algorithm, I try to divide sum of 2 values by 2

```
lst = list(x0)
for i, val in enumerate(lst):
    lst[i] = lst[i] + lst[i+1] / 2

x0 = tuple(lst)

plt.plot(x0, y0, label='nearest')
```

But it's not working correctly

Comment: `s/x = np.linspace(0, 8, len(x0)*2)/x = np.linspace(0, 8, )len(x0)*2-1)/`

Comment: Do you mean that you want the blue points connected by straight lines?

Comment: You have two interpolations here. You interpolated once with `interp1d`, and then `plt.plot` interpolates again with a different interpolation method to produce that line graph.

Comment: There are no curved lines here. The line graph makes straight connections between the points you gave it, which are *not* the points plotted by the blue dots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the green line is drawn as a connected graph between all the points, and you have too few points. Maybe you have misunderstood how `np.linspace` works. If you increase the number of points, (and change to plot only the points instead as connected lines) you will get a result that looks much more like you probably expect:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d
import math

# Original "data set" --- 21 random numbers between 0 and 1.
x0 = np.arange(9)
y0 = [math.sin(i) for i in x0]

plt.plot(x0, y0, 'o', label='Data')
plt.grid(linestyle="-", color=(0.7, 0.8, 1.0))

x = np.linspace(0, 8, 1000)

# Available options for interp1d
options = ('linear', 'nearest')

f = interp1d(x0, y0, kind='nearest')    # interpolation function
plt.plot(x, f(x), '.', label='nearest')      # plot of interpolated data

plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Ok, thanks is't works. How to do this interpolation without interp1d?

Comment: Why would you like to do that? I doubt there is much to gain in either performance or readability in doing it any other way.

Comment: I would like just try. I try divide two elements but it's not working correct `lst = list(x0)
for i, val in enumerate(lst):
    lst[i] = lst[i] + lst[i] / 2

x0 = tuple(lst) plt.plot(x0, y0, label='nearest')
`

Comment: Do you _want_ to do a 'nearest' or a 'linear' interpolation? In 'nearest', you should not calculate an average between values. You should round each `x` to the nearest `x0` and then use the correponding `y0` of that `x0`.

Comment: I want nearest interpolation

Comment: OK, it is not very hard, but there is not room for the answer in this comment and we are drifitng topic, so I think you should give it a try yourself and then come back with a new question if you do not manage to solve it yourself.